# What is the easiest way to run a .pdf displayed in combo box?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I have loaded the files to combo box...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"X:\BookStoreProject\WindowsFormsApplication2\Resources\PDF_Books");

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"X:\BookStoreProject\WindowsFormsApplication2\Resources\PDF_Books");
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf");
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            { 
                cboPDF.Items.Add(file);
            }
```

I now want to select the pdf from the combo box and load the pdf. But for some reason everything I try is not working. I can run a command (note this a different project)...

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Beginning Hibernate, 2006.pdf");
```

That is giving a direct string path, but my problem is maybe trying to recreate a path like this is the wrong direction?

Comment: Why do you think that would be a wrong direction? If you want to access a file, you do need some sort of path to it.

Comment: Note: I don't want to have to write a full string like this, I am looking to store the string so as I add new pdf books to the source file it is still available. Later to add more source files with choices in my form, i.e. C#, C++, Java etc. So I want to rewrite each path and store matching combo box selected item...the problem is getting that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Process.Start("Path_OF_Pdf.Exe", System.IO.Path.Combine("@X:\BookStoreProject\WindowsFormsApplication2\Resources\PDF_Books",cboPDF.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

You need to specify installation path of your PDF as your first parameter and name of pdf file as second.

**EDIT** from Shane's Comments

```
string w = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"X:\BookStoreProject\WindowsFormsApplication2\Resources\‌​PDF_Books\", cboPDF.SelectedItem.ToString());
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(w);
```

Comment: I tried this and still get errors. Add @ in front of ""X:\BookStore... to stop errors on escapes, then added System.Diagnostics.Process.Start as Precess by itself errors.

Comment: I also added an \ at the end of path, because I figured string from cboPDF will run into into of path. Not sure what gives here?

Comment: you need not to add '\' at the end of path thats what Path.Combine will do

Comment: I changed it around a little and got it to work like this............ 

string w = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"X:\BookStoreProject\WindowsFormsApplication2\Resources\PDF_Books\", cboPDF.SelectedItem.ToString());
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(w);

Comment: yep, that is perfect valid as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are having problems getting the full path from the combobox?

If this is actually your problem, the easiest way to do this is to create a new class that contains both the full path to the file, and the "friendly" name of the file that you want to display.  Let's call them .Path and .Name for this example.  Instantiate one of these classes for each file, and populate the .Path and .Name properties the way you want them, then add this instance to the combo box.  Set the ComboBox's .DisplayMember property to "Name", and .valueMember property to "Path".  this will cause the combo box to display the friendly name in the .Name property, but return whatever you put in the .Path property when you call ComboBox.SelectedValue.   Just use ComboBox.SelectedValue to get the path of the item.

If this isn't what you are actually having a problem with, please try to clarify your question so we can help you better.

Comment: Thanks for  the response Bradley, that was not exactly my issue but I will likely create a class as I grow this project.